# Применение нескольких регулярных выражений к строке

Tags: c#, регулярные-выражения

Как сделать так, чтобы в `pattern` можно было поместить массив регулярных выражений и выбрать то регулярное выражение, по которому найдено больше всего совпадений?

```
var str = Regex.Matches( input, pattern );
```

Answer (score 4):

Так не получится сделать, но можно пробегаясь по массиву регулярных выражений построить массив из `MatchCollection` и уже потом сравнивать всё, что Вам необходимо по этой полученной коллекции.

Правда я не очень понимаю, зачем такое может быть нужно. Как мне кажется, Вы что-то не то делаете.

Answer (score 2):

```
    var mostMatches = (from pattern in patterns select Regex.Matches(input, pattern)).OrderBy(x => x.Count)
        .LastOrDefault();
```